# How to make Assetic scan Twig templates outside bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

TLDR: How do I make Assetic scan for assets in Twig templates outside bundle?

I've got few registration wizards. Each of these wizards has it's own *view* directory, the file structure looks like this:

```
/SiteBundle/Wizard/General/Resources/views
/SiteBundle/Wizard/CountrySpecific/Resources/views
/SiteBundle/Wizard/[...several more...]/Resources/views
```

In config.yml I defined these paths for twig so I can use *@general_wizard/template.html.twig* paths:

```
twig:
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyWeb/SiteBundle/Wizard/General/Resources/views": general_wizard
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyWeb/SiteBundle/Wizard/CountrySpecific/Resources/views": country_specific_wizard
```

The problem is that assets used in these templates (inside the Wizard directories) are not dumped using *assetic:dump*. When I move the view sources to regular SiteBundle/Resources/views, then all the assets are correctly dumped.

Is there a way to make Assetic check the external templates too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with the stock `assetic:dump` (SF 2.3), as the `/Resources/views/` path is hardcoded in the GeneratorBundle, which again provides the list of files to process to assetic. Of course, you could write your own command, but you would basically reinvent the wheel.

I would recommend to keep with the `Resources/views` convention, and create the subcategories below that:

```
/SiteBundle/Resources/views/General
/SiteBundle/Resources/views/CountrySpecific
```

That would have the same effect, and would not require you to write your own commands and mess around with SF2 internals.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after moving all templates to `templates` in the project root, as it will probably come to be in future versions of Symfony.

The simplest solution is to configure all assets in the configuration file and to locate the output files in the `web` directory, e.g., all bootstrap CSS files into `web/css/bootstrap.css`. A remaining difficulty is that referencing the assets with the `javascripts` tag doesn't work anymore because those tags have to be scanned by the Assetic Bundle to work. You have to do this the old-fashioned way, e.g., via `{{ asset('css/bootstrap.js') }}`.

With Bootstrap I encountered difficulties to make Glyphicons work, since the `cssrewrite` filter doesn't work as before. I went for Fontawesome at that point, but including your own copy of Glyphicons could also work.